# How to make select value active after site reboot or button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Code:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="domnam" placeholder="Domain name"> </input>


    <select class="sel">
     <option value="Subdomain">Subdomain</option>
     <option value="IP">IP</option>
     <option value="WhoIS">WhoIS</option>
     <option value="Alexa">Alexa</option>
    </select>

     <input type="submit" value="Check" class="submitter"></input>
 </form>
```

After i click button or reboot the page select value doesn't change. LocalStorage also doesnt work.

```
$('.sel').on('change', function() {
    localStorage.setItem('todoData', $('.sel').val());

if (localStorage.getItem('todoData')){
    $('.sel').val(localStorage.getItem('todoData'));
}
});
```

Comment: Thats now how you close input elements -  You are also doing all that on `change`

Answer (score 0):

Just put your `localStorage.getItem` outside of `onchange`.

```
window.onload = function () {
    if (window.jQuery) {
        if (window.localStorage.getItem('todoData')) {

            document.getElementById("mySelect").value = window.localStorage.getItem('todoData');
        }

        $('.sel').on('change', function () {
            console.log($('.sel').val());
            window.localStorage.setItem('todoData', $('.sel').val());
        });

        console.log("JQuery is loaded.");
    } else {
        console.log("JQuery is not loaded.");
    }
}
```

In the past, I added the answer by snippet and due to `Block third-party cookies and site data` purpose, `localStorage` wasn't found.

Comment: Your HTML is not correct. please review you answer - An answer should not code only. Please add some explanation how this can solve the issue of OP.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping, It was working in my browser. I thought this should work on snippet as well. But due to `Block third-party cookies and site data` this, `localStorage` was not found. I updated it. And thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close the parentheses correctly
2. Use document ready handler to manipulate the page after it has fully loaded.

```
$('.sel').on('change', function() {
    localStorage.setItem('todoData', $('.sel').val());
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('todoData')){
        $('.sel').val(localStorage.getItem('todoData'));
    }
});
```

Comment: An answer should not code only. Please add some explanation how this will solve the issue of OP.

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues in your code and HTML

1. You are not closing the inputs correctly use `/>` to close inputs
2. Using getItem inside on change will not work as you have select something from drop down for getItem to work.
3. Also, consider using `window.localStorage` instead of doing `localStorage`

Change your `HTML` and `jQuery` to the following to use `localStorage`

This code is tested and is working on my website.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="domnam" id="domain_name" placeholder="Domain name" />

<select class="sel">
 <option value="Subdomain">Subdomain</option>
 <option value="IP">IP</option>
 <option value="WhoIS">WhoIS</option>
 <option value="Alexa">Alexa</option>
</select>

 <input type="submit" value="Check" class="submitter" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.sel').on('change', function() {
  window.localStorage.setItem('todoData', $('.sel').val());
  window.localStorage.setItem('domainName', $('#domain_name').val());
});

if (window.localStorage.getItem('todoData')){
    $('.sel').val(window.localStorage.getItem('todoData'));
    $('#domain_name').val(window.localStorage.getItem('domainName'));
}
```